Invoke-SSHCommand in SNR Switch for user mode
If i have a switch which start ssh session with user mode, i need to enter 'enable' to move privilege mode. I use PowerShell module SSHSessions version 2.1.3 and send this command:
(Invoke-SSHCommand -InvokeOnAll -Command "enable").Result

or
(Invoke-SSHCommand -ComputerName $SwitchIPAddress -Command "enable").Result

But return this message:
[$SwitchIPAddress] had an error: imish: invalid option -- c Try imish --help' for more information.  imish: invalid option -- c Try imish --help' for more information.

In common any sent command to this Switch return this error above
Switch model: SNR-S5210X-8F
What I do wrong?

https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/getting-imish-error-when-executing-command-on-ssh-connection-4175635246/#post5885519 provides some pointers. In short: it seems that the shell running on the switch doesn't understand the -c CLI option for passing commands, which SSH uses behind the scenes. Use -v and -vv to get diagnostic output. On Unix-like systems, scripting the interaction with the switch using the expect utility may be an option (but I presume you couldn't use the PowerShell module then).
